# How do i print image title in custom node for image gallery

Tags: nodes, media

I use content types for image gallery and write own custom node for image gallery all images are show in custom node by following code but i don't know how to print the image title.

In this code i have given static title 'Circles and Cycles ' and i need dynamically title of every image.

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node-gallery">
<ul class="product-grid">

    <?php
        $imgcount = count($node->field_gallery_image['und']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $imgcount; $i++) {
        $image_uri = $node->field_gallery_image['und'][$i]['uri'];
            // url
            $masthead_raw = image_style_url('gallery-thumb', $image_uri);

    ?>
      <li>
        <div class="main-product-wrapper">
          <a href="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_gallery_image['und'][$i]['uri']); ?>" rel="group-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="product-link">
       <div class="product-item"> <img class="image<?php print ($i + 1);?>" src="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>" /></div></a>
          <div class="product-title"><a href="#">Circles and Cycles</a></div>

      </li>
      <?php
        }?>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

[image: The gallery page]

Answer (score 0):

Create a `view` of your content type, then in this view select the `fields` as your content and then select the `title` and the `image`. then every image will have its own title. you can also theme it in any way that you want.

you need to output this `view` in your node page, so simply in your `template.php` and in `hook_preprocess_node` function suggest a theme hook for this content type (for example `page--node--gallery.tpl.php`) and then in the `page--node--gallery.tpl.php` output the view using `views_embed_view("view_name","display")`.

Comment: sir, i want to print the image title programmatically at node--gallery.tpl.php like image without making view.

Comment: It is possible to create a view and embed it in the node page. But I'm surprising why you are insisting on doing this with out the views while views make it very easy !